# webClient.DownloadData to byte[]

Tags: .net

I have a code which I am using for measure internet speed. the code is looks working perfectly on local but when I use it on server gives the error "Attempted to divide by zero." also temp.tostring() returns "byte[]0"

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw;
Byte[] temp;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();

    sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    try
    {
        temp = webClient.DownloadData("http://www.xxx.com/yyy.rar");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
    sw.Stop();

    long speed = temp.Length / sw.Elapsed.Seconds;

    Response.Write(Convert.ToInt32((speed / 1000)).ToString());
}
```

UPDATE!

Its turns out my logic was wrong about measuring users internet speed like this. this code downloaddata locally, so done in some miliseconds. What should I do to measure users internet speed?

Comment: Your download may complete in less than one second, so `sw.Elapsed.Seconds` would be zero.

Comment: hmm but the file and code works on same server so some how code works kind of local?

Comment: And on a server, where you may have quite a lot of bandwidth for downloading, 14mb can easily download in under a second.

Comment: so this is measures kind of servers speed, not the users. what should I do to measure users?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably dividing by zero because

```
sw.Elapsed.Seconds
```

is zero.  `Seconds` is of type `int`, so if the response is fast it will be zero.  Use *Milliseconds* for reasonable precision and in any event check for zero.

If `temp` contains no data, no data was returned in your request either because the URL could not be resolved (did the Exception handler run?) or because the webserver returned an HTTP code of 200, but an empty response body.

Answer (score 0):

What you meant was `sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds`. `Seconds` are wall-clock seconds (wrapping around to zero, or starting at zero for one sec).

The stack trace would have told you that. I was forced to guess. Not a good strategy to debug.

Also you keep going if an exception happens. You also need to test the exceptional case locally - you would have found the error.

Comment: locally works fine. do you mean should I choose local file while I test locally?

Comment: I meant download an invalid URL so your catch is hit - and you can check that everything works (it won't...). Anyway, the divbyzero has only one place where it could have occurred. Do you agree? Seconds MUST have been 0.

Comment: I hope I don't come across unfriendly. I'm trying to teach you debugging practices. I don't want you to solve just this one problem but want to teach you the skill to debug *any* problem yourself. Staring at code is not debugging :)

Comment: any behavior is fine as long as useful. but I guess problem is the file and code works on same server so never user uses his bandwidth to download it. and Its like some milisec to download locally. the problem is this. that's why I get 0 sec. so my logic is wrong to measure users internet speed like this.